# jQuery - hasClass on html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`$(html).hasClass("class")`, `$(document).hasClass("class")`, `$(document.html).hasClass("class")`
None works. What selector should I use to get the class of the  tag ?
Also, how can I find a list of standard elements which I can select in jQuery ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('html').hasClass("class");
```

- **`[!]`** You forgot to type quotation around `html`.

[Here you can find all jQuery Selectors.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

---

### Extra Information

The [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method will return `boolean`. You can access the **class name** by getting the `class` attribute with `.attr()` method:

```
<div class="a" id="example1"></div>
var c = $('#element').attr('class'); // (string) a
```

If your element has multiple classes, you can split the string to convert it to an array:

```
<div class="a b c" id="example2"></div>
var k = $('#example2').attr('class').split(/\s+/); // [a, b, c]
```

Here is the <kbd>**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/DTQZD/)**</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

> "What selector should I use to get the class of the tag?"

The other answers use `hasClass()`, **which returns a boolean not a class**:

```
$('html').attr('class');
```

Comment: You are right, but it is not what I meant. I edited it, thanks for making me notice and sorry for the inconvenience, I'll +1 your answer but take another one which is more complete in this case

Comment: @user2316341 You shouldn't edit your question like that. Accepting the other answer is fine, but I don't deserve future downvotes based on your question change, so it's being rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

```
<html class="someClass">
</html>
```

Do this -

```
$('html').hasClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 3):

Your DOM is structured like this, basically:

```
- document
  - documentElement
    - head
    - body
```

You can either use jQuery's internal selector engine by writing `$('html').hasClass('class')` or you can target the HTML element yourself by writing `$(document.documentElement).hasClass('class')`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<div`> has an id:

```
​<div id="test" class="my-custom-class"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

...you can try:

```
var yourClass = $("#test").prop("class");
```

If your  has only a class, you can try:

```
var yourClass = $(".my-custom-class").prop("class");
```